# "Finding possible candy permutations" HackerEarth challenge

Tags: python, programming-challenge, combinatorics, time-limit-exceeded

> **Problem Statement**
>
> Shil, Aditya and Utkarsh go to a candy shop. There are N candies
>   present in the shop, which are indexed from 1 to N. All three of them
>   select one candy to eat.
>
> However, a candy tastes delicious if and only if, the index of candy
>   chosen by Shil is strictly less than the index of candy chosen by
>   Aditya and the index of candy chosen by Aditya is strictly greater
>   than index of candy chosen by Utkarsh.
>
> To state in simple Mathematical terms, if Shil chooses ith candy,
>   Aditya chooses jth candy and Utkarsh chooses kth candy, then the
>   candies would taste delicious
>
> **if and only if i < j and j > k.**
>
> You have to find the total number of ways in which they can choose
>   candies such that the candies would taste delicious to them. Note that
>   all of them choose distinct number of candies i.e., i!=j and j!=k and
>   i!=k.
>
> **Input format:**
>
> The only line of input consists of a single integer N denoting the total number of candies.
>
> **Output format:**
>
> Find the total number of ways by which all three can choose candies such that the candies would taste delicious
>   to them.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> \$3 \le N \le 1000\$
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 4
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 8
> ```
>
> **Explanation:**
>  All the possible ways to choose candies are:
>
> ```
> [1,3,2]
> [2,3,1]
> [2,4,3]
> [3,4,2]
> [1,4,3]
> [3,4,1]
> [2,4,1]
> [1,4,2]
> ```
>
> The first integer in all the tuples denotes index of candy chosen by
>   Shil, the second integer denotes index of candy chosen by Aditya and
>   the third integer denotes index of candy chosen by Utkarsh.

---

```
from itertools import permutations
n=int(raw_input())
n=[x for x in range(1,n+1)]
count=0
for i,j,k in permutations(n,3):
    if i<j and j>k:
        count+=1
print count
```

Comment: Can you please add a link to the contest's page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a waste to explore the entire permutation space.
There's a simpler way to calculate the possible combinations using basic combinatorics principles:

- One number can be selected from the range `1 .. n`
- One number can be selected from the range `1 .. n-1`
- One number can be selected from the range `1 .. n-2`

There are `n * (n - 1) * (n - 2)` combinations like this,
but that includes `n` in the first, second, and third positions.
You need to exclude the combinations where `n` is in the first and third position, so you need to divide it by 3.

```
def get_candy_permutations_count(n):
    """
    >>> get_candy_permutations_count(3)
    2
    >>> get_candy_permutations_count(4)
    8
    >>> get_candy_permutations_count(5)
    20
    >>> get_candy_permutations_count(6)
    40
    """
    return n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) // 3
```

Note the truncating integer division.
This is safe to do, as the number of combinations is always necessarily a multiple of 3.